# glDisableClientState in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm just wondering why we need to call `glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` after the drawing of a vertex array. Is it possible to just leave it there for the next drawing? Is there any side effect of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to mention that client-side vertex arrays are deprecated in OpenGL 3.0 and removed in OpenGL 3.1 and above.

To answer your question: you can call `glEnableClientState` once and leave the state enabled as far as your drawing code requires the same state. For example, if you don't want to render normals arrays you don't want it to be enabled, so you call `glDisableClientState`.

Performance wise it's better not to change states too often, but it's *usually* impractical to leave some states always enabled, hence affecting the whole application.

Also note that drivers that support OpenGL 3 and above will use temporary vertex buffer objects (VBOs) whenever you use non-VBO functions, because it needs to copy your data in case you modified it in your user space code.

Comment: Thanks! May I know how to accelerate my OpenGL program? I've tried use some display lists but haven't noticed a big performance boost. How does that compare to VBOs?

Comment: well you may want to check my other answers on this topic:http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9704/generating-geometry-when-using-vbo/9760#9760

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9524/opengl-performance-questions/9529#9529